# How do I convert a parametric surface $S(u,v) = (X(u,v),Y(u,v),Z(u,v))$ to a Monge representation

Tags: linear-algebra, surfaces

How do I convert a parametric surface

$S(u,v) = (X(u,v),Y(u,v),Z(u,v)) $

to a Monge representation,

$ S(x,y) = (x,y,Z(x,y))$?

Comment: In such situation, the cost of converting, the $Z$ will be modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try solving the system

$$\begin{cases} x=X(u,v) \\y=Y(u,v) \end{cases} $$
for the functions $u=u(x,y),v=v(x,y)$. After that you can reparametrize as

$$(x,y,Z(u(x,y),v(x,y))) .$$